# Bourdet Derivative in R with Smoothing Window

Tags: r, loops, iteration, smoothing, derivative

I am calculating pressure derivatives using algorithms from this PDF:

[Derivative Algorithms](http://infohost.nmt.edu/~petro/faculty/Kelly/450/derv.pdf)

I have been able to implement the "two-points" and "three-consecutive-points" methods relatively easily using dplyr's lag/lead functions to offset the original columns forward and back one row.

The issue with those two methods is that there can be a ton of noise in the high resolution data we use. This is why there is the third method, "three-smoothed-points" which is significantly more difficult to implement. There is a user-defined "window width",*W*, that is typically between 0 and 0.5. The algorithm chooses point_L and point_R as being the first ones such that *ln(deltaP/deltaP_L) >* *W* and *ln(deltaP/deltaP_R) >* *W*. Here is what I have so far:

```
#If necessary install DPLYR

#install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

#Create initial Data Frame
elapsedTime <- c(0.09583, 0.10833, 0.12083, 0.13333, 0.14583, 0.1680, 
0.18383, 0.25583)
deltaP <- c(71.95, 80.68,   88.39, 97.12, 104.24, 108.34, 110.67, 122.29)
df <- data.frame(elapsedTime,deltaP)

#Shift the elapsedTime and deltaP columns forward and back one row
df$lagTime <- lag(df$elapsedTime,1)
df$leadTime <- lead(df$elapsedTime,1)
df$lagP <- lag(df$deltaP,1)
df$leadP <- lead(df$deltaP,1)

#Calculate the 2 and 3 point derivatives using nearest neighbors
df$TwoPtDer <- (df$leadP - df$lagP) / log(df$leadTime/df$lagTime)

df$ThreeConsDer <- ((df$deltaP-df$lagP)/(log(df$elapsedTime/df$lagTime)))*               
((log(df$leadTime/df$elapsedTime))/(log(df$leadTime/df$lagTime))) +
((df$leadP-df$deltaP)/(log(df$leadTime/df$elapsedTime)))*                  
((log(df$elapsedTime/df$lagTime))/(log(df$leadTime/df$lagTime)))

#Calculate the window value for the current 1 row shift
df$lnDeltaT_left <- abs(log(df$elapsedTime/df$lagTime))
df$lnDeltaT_right <- abs(log(df$elapsedTime/df$leadTime))
```

[Resulting Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzJ8C.png)

If you look at the picture linked above, you will see that based on a *W* of 0.1, only row 2 matches this criteria for both the left and right point. Just FYI, this data set is an extension of the data used in *example 2.5* in the referenced PDF.

So, my ultimate question is this:
How can I choose the correct point_L and point_R such that they meet the above criteria? My initial thoughts are some kind of while loop, but being an inexperienced programmer, I am having trouble writing a loop that gets anywhere close to what I am shooting for.

Thank you for any suggestions you may have!